# jQuery animation Hide/FadeIn/FadeOut etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a nice effect on the photogalery on http://triple-g.eu/fotogalerij.html
Right now i have a fade out from the big image to a smaller image.

How could i make the transition from big to the smaller format nicer?

**Code right now:**

```
$("#thumbnails img").each(function(index) {
    $(this).hide().delay(100*index).fadeIn(750);
});

setTimeout(function()
{
    $("li#hide").fadeOut(3500, function ()
    {
        $("li#hide img").remove();                
            $("li#hide2").show();
    });
 }, 1000);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3g1t0unk/)

Comment: what do you mean by *nicer*?

Comment: Could you simply configure the size properties (height, width) with a transition in the CSS of the big image?Then instead of hiding a big version and showing the smaller one you simply set the size of the image to a smaller one. The rest of the images will probably still be a bit "jumpy" in their move...

Comment: Right now the galery loads all the images (with a fadein) the big eyecatcher image fadesout and the smaller version apears. but its not like a nice transition between the big image and the small image it is a fadeout from the big image and the small image just popsout..

I will check the CSS transitions out thanks didn't think about that one =)

Comment: add your HTML only related to the image part with this question and create a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Aminul // I have added a fidle. the images dont work.. not really known with the JSFiddle